# Change process button from agile to scrum is missing in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to change process from agile to scrum in azure DevOps but the change process button is missing. While i changed the "Change process of team project" setting in project settings.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your permissions required to perform the change process operation?

Pre-requisites

- To create, delete or edit a process, you must be a member of the [Project Collection Administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions) group, or have the corresponding permissions Create process, Delete process, Edit process, or Delete a field from organization set to Allow. See [Set permissions and access for work tracking, Customize an inherited process.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking#customize-an-inherited-process)
- Users granted Basic or Stakeholder access can be granted permissions to create, edit, and delete processes, and administer process permissions.

Learn details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

> Change process button from agile to scrum is missing in azure devops

According to the image you provided, it seems you are using the **Azure devops Server** instead of the Azure devops service, which does not support this feature to change the process from agile to scrum.

To change the process from agile to scrum on Azure devops Server, you could check following ticket for some more details:

[Is it possible to migrate from Agile to Scrum based project](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/44)

If you are using Azure devops service, you need to check if you meet the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-agile-to-scrum?view=azure-devops#prerequisites), then **select the project**, you will see options:

[image]

Hope this helps.